# ValueError: '%' is a bad directive in format '%d%^b%y'

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, string-to-datetime

I am trying to convert string to datetime. The string syntax is 30JUN21.

Code:

```
df.column = pd.to_datetime(df.column, , format='%d%^b%y')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: '%' is a bad directive in format '%d%^b%y'
```

I am pretty sure this error relates to the caret. I don't know another way around the upper case month abbreviations.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

Comment: Did you try `%d%b%y` and find some problem with it?

Comment: You don't need the caret

Comment: There's no way to specify "uppercase `%b`", because `%b` already doesn't falter on case.

Comment: @mechanical If that helped, then it should also work as is (which it does), since the manual gives Titlecased examples and not lowercased examples.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a caret was allowed?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([("Date1","NewDate")],columns=["30JUN21","30MAR22"])

df.columns = [pd.to_datetime(column, format='%d%b%y') for column in df.columns]
print(df)
```

output:

```
  2021-06-30 2022-03-30

0      Date1    NewDate
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this doesn't handle the case issue

Comment: ok let me try this, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that directives are case sensitive. I received the data in upper case. The following code resolved the issue.

```py
df.column = pd.to_datetime(df.column.title(), format='%d%b%y')
```